# bigquery: join to a "struct" column

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

So I have one flatten (normal) table (table a) in bigquery and another one (table b) which has several struct columns. I need to join these two table. But the challenge is that I need to use the id in the table a and join it to an id in table b which is a "struct" type. I tried to use the "UNNEST" clause intially but later learned that I could use it only for "ARRAY" types.

I then tried the following code"

```
select a.user_id
from `table_a` a
join `table_b` b
on a.user_id = b.prices.cars_user_ids
limit 10
```

(the reason that I used the .price. is because it is a struct)

But unfortunately I get the following error:

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, ARRAY<STRING>. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [4:4]
```

I understand why it is complaining. but the only solution that came to my mind was to use the "UNNEST" function. And again, it would not work since it is not an array. Could you please help?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not mention a struct at all, but an array.  I suspect you want:

```
select a.user_id
from `table_a` a join
     (`table_b` b cross join
      unnest(b.prices) price
     )
     on a.user_id = price.cars_user_ids;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggest but it gives me the following error:
``` Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT<registered ARRAY<STRING>, cars_user_ids ARRAY<STRING>, ...> at [5:8] ```

Comment: Not all questions can or should be answered here. Avoid trying to answer questions [which...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Answer%20well-asked%20questions)